# How to prevent document editing and properties updating

Tags: document-library, event-handlers, event-receivers, document, updatelistitems

I need to be able to prevent the document in document library to be edited and it's properties updated when the custom document property `DocState` has a value `Reviewed`. Should I use document library event handlers? If yes, how?

Pseudo code

```
SPListItem document;
document = this.Web.Lists["Document Library Title"].GetItemById(x);
...
if (document["DocState"].ToString() == "Reviewed")
{
  // preventDocumentContentEditing!
  // preventDocumentPropertiesUpdating!
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SPItemEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) to create your own event receiver. In your receiver you can implement [ItemUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating.aspx) method. In this method you can retrieve item from [SPItemEventProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.aspx). Compare item field value with your value and use following code to cancel update:

```
properties.Cancel = true;
properties.ErrorMessage = "you can not update this item";
```

Comment: Great! Would that prevent both document content editing and properties updating? I am asking because I am not sure whether ItemUpdating would stop the user from opening the document in, say, Word and modify it's content.

Comment: This event is handled when the user click Save Button. If you would like to prevent update action when the user opens an item, you can create custom edit form, on this form you can put a label with message and hide other controls.

Comment: So there is no property on the SPListItem or SPFile that I could use to make it read-only?

Comment: As I know you can set read only property to the document that is stored in the list by receiver... but I don't know how does it work with document metadata that are displayed in edit form. Also this approach is not applicable to the item of a list.